# how to disable the trackstick in dell?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

How to disable the trackstick which is in between the keys of the Dell laptop keyboard. It really causes a lot of problem while typing.

Answer (score 13):

Go to the terminal and type the following:

```
xinput -set-prop "DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0
```

Comment: on ubuntu 16.04 this and toshiba portege this successfully disable joystick, but touchpad stops sending click events

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 `xinput -set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0`

Answer (score 12):

### How to disable the trackstick in Dell laptops

2 Commands to disable it, and 1 additional step to make this persistent across reboots:

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

1. `xinput`

   Here is my output, for example:

   [image]

   The key line we care about is the "DualPoint Stick". Mine is the 7th line down:

   ```
   ⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ```

   Take note of its id number (15 in my case), then use that in the next command:
2. **To disable it:**

   ```
   xinput --disable 15
   ```

   You might also try the following, as recommended by @[Brent Zundel](https://askubuntu.com/users/705080/brent-zundel) in his comment under this answer:

   ```
   xinput --set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0
   ```

   **If you'd ever like to re-enable it, try the following:**

   ```
   xinput --enable 15
   ```

   OR

   ```
   xinput --set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 1
   ```

   See `man xinput` for more details.
3. Now the problem is that our change above is not **persistent across reboots**. To fix that do the following:

   1. Open the "Startup Applications" program in Ubuntu.
   2. Click "Add" to add an additional startup program.
   3. Put your disable command from above (ex: `xinput --disable 15`) into the "Command" box, and anything you want into the "Name" and "Comment" boxes. Mine looks like this:

      - [image]
      - See also the comment under this answer from @[Brent Zundel](https://askubuntu.com/users/705080/brent-zundel). He recommends you use the following command instead, to ensure that it always works even if the device ID number changes: `xinput -set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0`.
   4. Click "Add" and then "Close".

   Done! Now it will run this script every time you reboot, thereby automatically disabling it again.

   *Note: if you think you can place this command in `/etc/rc.local` instead, to run at startup, it probably won't work since xinput requires the X Window System to be running. See here: [Why won't rc.local run xinput?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534203/why-wont-rc-local-run-xinput). In either case, I couldn't get it to work that way, even with adding `sleep 10` before the command.* But, adding it to the "Startup Applications" as I explain above *does* work.

### Related:

1. See my **touchpad_toggle.sh** script in my dotfiles project: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles.

### References:

1. Thanks to [@YetAnotherG33k's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/120438/327339) for first getting me on the right track by informing me about `xinput`.
2. And thanks to @Brent Zundel for his comment below my answer too.

Comment: I would recommend combining this, much more complete answer with @YetAnotherG33k's answer, as the xinput id number of the trackstick may change over time. In step 3 of your directions for making the change persistent across reboots, it would be better to use `xinput -set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0` as the command, rather than  `xinput --disable 15`

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/touchpad_toggle.sh

Answer (score 1):

In addition to fine answer of Gabriel Staples I'd like to mention that in some Dell laptop models xinput's output may not contain any sign of pointing stick. In my case (Latitude 5591 laptop) it was "DELL0819:00 044E:121F Mouse" with "id=13" and disabling it with `xinput --disable 13` helped.

What can you do to find out the name of the pointing stick device in that case? Try `grep "input device" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` output, the desired device should have `type: MOUSE`. Corresponding `id` should be the one you are looking for.

More universal way of disabling pointing stick which should work both in X and in Wayland is to use udev rules. If you are using Wayland then xinput tool will be unavailable.
First run `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` and scan its output for the devices with `Handlers` containing the word `mouse`. One of them will be the pointing stick. Notice its `Name` field, we will use it later (in my case it was "DELL0819:00 044E:121F Mouse", as I mentioned earlier). Then copy the long value of `Sysfs` field of this device and use it in the next command. In my case it was:

```
udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-DELL0819:00/0018:044E:121F.0001/input/input24
```

The output of this command should contain several parameters starting with ID_INPUT. Combining the name of our pointing stick and these parameters we can create the rule:

```
ATTRS{name}=="DELL0819:00 044E:121F Mouse", ENV{ID_INPUT}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_MOUSE}="", ENV{ID_INPUT_POINTINGSTICK}=""
```

Now create the file `99-pointstick-off.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` folder and add the rule there. Reboot. Pointing stick should be disabled now.

The insight regarding this method I gained [here](https://cederlys.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/disabling-the-track-stick-in-ubuntu/#comment-874).

Answer (score 0):

Adapting form YetAnotherG33k's answer:

On Debian GNU/Linux 11 running KDE Plasma Version 5.20.5 this did the trick for me:

1. Find the device name of the notebook's dualpoint stick:

```
xinput list | grep "DualPoint Stick"
```

Output:

```
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

2. Copy the device name. In my case it's called *"AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick"* and insert it in:

```
xinput -set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick" "Device Enabled" 0
```

This solution is better than disabling the device using a device ID as the device ID could change overtime, thus resulting in disabling the wrong device.