# Why won't rc.local run xinput?

Tags: boot, keyboard, startup, startup-applications, xinput

I added this command to the `rc.local` file:

```
xinput float 12
```

Then I saved the file. But when I reboot my PC, Ubuntu doesn't execute this command, cause the internal keyboard of my laptop is still working. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the command *is* being executed.

The `xinput float` technique given in [Is there a way to disable a laptop's internal keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard) works... but not if you run it from `rc.local`. [`xinput`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xinput.1.html) requires the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) to be running. But it's not running yet at the time `rc.local` is executed.

Most of the time, the best solution is to have your `xinput` command run automatically every time you log in graphically. See:

- [How do I make a program auto-start everytime I log in in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459277/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in-in-ubuntu-14-04)
- [How do I make a program auto-start every time I log in?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in)

Open Startup Applications (you can search for it in the dash). In the Startup Programs tab of the Startup Applications Preferences window, click the Add button.

[image: screenshot showing how to make a startup entry for an xinput float command]
<sup>I took this screenshot on a MATE desktop, but if you use Ubuntu's default Unity desktop, or GNOME Shell, it's the same.</sup>

Fill in the fields:

- Put whatever you want for *Name*. It should probably be something descriptive, like "Disable Internal Keyboard."
- For *Command*, put `xinput float 12` (assuming 12 is the number of the device you wish to disable, as shown in the output of `xinput list`).
- *Comment* is optional.

Then click Add.

Log out and back in, to check if it works.