# failed to start etc/rc.local error after updating to Wily

Tags: boot, startup, zsh, 15.10

After upgrading to Wily I get this error "`failed to start etc/rc.local`" It also says see "`systemctl rc-local.service ubuntu`":

[image: startup]

I am getting problems each time I want to modify **/.zshrc** it tells me another one is using it, suggesting if I want to recover it.

I am using ohmyzsh as a terminal and editing ~/.zshrc to add programs to the PATH. Using Ubuntu GNOME. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it /etc/rc.local or etc/rc.local? What does this tell us? `cat  /etc/rc.local`?

Comment: This

#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
xinput -set-prop  13 139 0
exit 0

I added that xinput line to fix some wrong behavior with the trackpoint.

Comment: I wonder if this is the problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/534203/why-wont-rc-local-run-xinput Please note: `xinput requires the X Window System to be running. But it's not running yet at the time rc.local is executed.`

Comment: Thanks, I removed that xinput line at it worked! It wasn't working properly anyway and was fixing the trackpoint issue with a custom script.

Comment: @chili555: you should add your comment as answer, so the questioner can accept your Answer as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I removed that xinput line at it worked!